# Comparison between 3 values

Tags: bash, compare

In a bash shell I have to determine if three values are equal to each other

```
if [val1 == val2 == val3]; then
do something
else
do other
fi
```

But it doesn't seem to work (too many arguments)
Where am I doing wrong?
Thanks
Massimo

Comment: You need a space between the `[` and  `]`

Comment: Here are a couple of ways of doing this in [tag:bash]: `[ "${string1}" = "${string2}" ] && [ "${string2}" = "${string3}" ]` or `[[ "${string1}" == "${string2}" && "${string2}" == "${string3}" ]]`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make two comparisons.

```
if [ "$val1" = "$val2" ] && [ "$val2" = "$val3" ]; then
do something
else
do other
fi
```

This takes advantage of the fact that all equivalence relations are transitive: if `val1 = val2` and `val2 = val3`, then `val1 = val3` must be true as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just because we can do it more complicated:

```
declare -A a=( [a$var1]= [a$var2]= [a$var3]= )
if [[ "${#a[@]}" == 1 ]]; then echo equal; else echo not equal; fi
unset a
```

The idea is to create an associative array `a` with key-value pairs. In the above, the value is always an empty string, so we only care about the keys. The keys in the above are `a$var1`, `a$var2` and `a$var3`. If any of these keys are identical, then it is as if we defined only a single one. I.e.

```
 declare -A a ( [aa]= [ab]= [aa]= )
```

is equivalent to

```
 declare -A a ( [aa]= [ab]= )
```

The value `${#a[@]}` returns the total number of entries in the array. So if that is equal to one, it implies that all values are identical.

We prefix the keys with a character (here `a`) to ensure that the variables can be anything, including empty strings, `@` and `*`. Thanks to [Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544493/comparison-between-3-values/60548192?noredirect=1#comment107126237_60548192) for pointing this out.

Comment: Is this `val1=asdlkjm2354l val2=$val1 val3='sdf;lkjsdfs235lk;4j25'` equal?

Comment: @Ivan how do you get these values? Do they mark equal?

Answer (score 1):

Let's agree again on 1 law, if `a=b` AND `b=c` then it will be `a=b=c`. Considering that try changing your condition to (BTW IMHO I don't think that bash allows `a==b==c` type if conditions though Python does if I am correct here):

```
if [[ "$val1" -eq "$val2" && "$val2" -eq "$val3" ]]
then
  do something
else
  do other
fi
```

***Example run:***

Lets say we have following script with 3 of the variable values:

```
$ cat script.bash
#!/bin/bash
val1="1"
val2="1"
val3="1"
if [[ "$val1" -eq "$val2" && "$val2" -eq "$val3" ]]
then
  echo "do something"
else
  echo "do other"
fi
```

Now when we run it as:

```
$ ./script.bash
do something
```

Answer (score -3):

If all values are digits this may work(not)

```
$ val1=1 val2=1 val3=1
$ ((val1==val2==val3)) && echo ok || echo fail
ok

$ val1=1 val2=2 val3=1
$ ((val1==val2==val3)) && echo ok || echo fail
fail
```

Then like this

```
$ val1=3 val2=3 val3=3
$ [[ "$val1 $val1" == "$val2 $val3" ]] && echo ok || echo fail
ok

$ val1=3 val2=3 val3=a2
$ [[ "$val1 $val1" == "$val2 $val3" ]] && echo ok || echo fail
fail

$ val1=asdlkjm2354l val2=$val1 val3=$val1
$ [[ "$val1 $val1" == "$val2 $val3" ]] && echo ok || echo fail
ok

$ val1=asdlkjm2354l val2=$val1 val3='sdf;lkjsdfs235lk;4j25'
$ [[ "$val1 $val1" == "$val2 $val3" ]] && echo ok || echo fail
fail
```

With `(())` also works

```
$ val1=3 val2=3 val3=3
$ (($val1$val1==$val2$val3)) && echo ok || echo fail
ok

$ val1=33 val2=3 val3=33
$ (($val1$val1==$val2$val3)) && echo ok || echo fail
fail
```

Comment: @Ivan with RANDOM it cannot work. There is always a counter example. We are searching for a robust 100% bulletproof version which works for any possible case. The random is a nice touch, but if by _chance_ our strings are exactly the same as `val1=x${D}x, val2=x, val3=x${D}x${D}x`, then by chance it will mark as matching, while it does not.